# Find next occurance of a given time after given timestamp

Tags: php, php-carbon

Given an arbitrary timestamp (e.g. `2019-02-26 10:30:00`) I would like to find the next occurrence of an arbitrary time.

For example, the next occurrence of `12:00:00` will be `2019-02-26 12:00:00` but the next occurrence of `09:00:00` will be the next day at `2019-02-27 09:00:00`. The results could be `Carbon` or `Datetime` objects. The test time will just be a string as shown.

Is there a way to calculate this in native PHP or PHP Carbon without conditionally boxing in time periods. An obvious way would be to see if the time being tested is past the check time for `today`, and if it is, taking the result as the check time plus 24 hours (the next day). That feels to me like too much chopping and joining of dates and times, so is there a way to calculate it by considering time to be a simple linear line?

All times will be in a single timezone, with DST. Note: the arbitrary datetimes and check times will stay clear of DST changeovers i.e. `01:00` to `02:00` so hopefully they will not be an issue to take into account.

Comment: Hi, maybe if you gave us an example to explain what you want to find based on where you are starting from

Comment: The first two paragraphs hopefully give that. Those datatimes can be a php `Datetime` or `Carbon` objects.

Comment: @Jason, it's not clear what you are trying to do. What determines the times you need to find (i.e. 9:00 or 12:00)? If your only concern is whether it is current day or next day, that's easy to find out.

Comment: Why not research the DateTime Class and the Diff functionality within it. Thats how I would approach this I think

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not start with some code and share it, such that others could provide improvement ideas?

Comment: @nico-haase agreed - I just could not get my head around it, overthinking the problem. I've pasted some code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no for PHP (partial answer, I'm no specialist of Carbon but from quick look it's also no, but you can create a macro from following code).

However, with a ternary condition the one-liner is simple enough IMHO (replace the second `DateTime($str)` with `DateTime()` if you want to compare with current date and time, and change the `>=` by `>` if you want next day when time compared is exactly the same):

```
$str = '2019-02-26 10:30:00';

$date1 = ( ($a = (new DateTime($str))->setTime(12,00)) >= (new DateTime($str)) ) ? $a : $a->modify('+1 day');

$date2 = ( ($a = (new DateTime($str))->setTime(9,00)) >= (new DateTime($str)) ) ? $a : $a->modify('+1 day');

echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2019-02-26 12:00:00
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2019-02-27 09:00:00
```

quick note: what you gave us is not a timestamp, but a formatted date.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am using now through `Carbon`, which appears to give me the correct results:

```
        $dateTime = Carbon::parse('2019-03-30 17:34:50', 'Europe/London');

        $testTime = '16:00:00';

        list ($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $testTime);

        $nextTimeOccurrence = $dateTime
            ->copy() // Carbon 1 only
            ->hour($hour)->minute($minute)->second($second);

        if ($dateTime->gt($nextTimeOccurrence)) {
            $nextTimeOccurrence = $nextTimeOccurrence->addDay();
        }

        // $nextTimeOccurrence is the next occurrence of $testTime after $dateTime
```

The splitting of the time seems clumsy, but might be the best way? The approach is:

- Create a timestamp with the test time on the same day as the timestamp I'm checking. This will be the timestamp I am looking for.
- If the timestamp I'm checking is after the timestamp created in the previous step, then add a day to it.

I've tested this around DST, and happily Carbon/Datetime keeps the same time when adding a day over a DST period, where a day there would be 25 hours or 23 hours, depending on which way it goes.

I still think there is a more "linear time" way to do this, but this seems simple and robust. Thanks go to @michael-stokoe here at the office for my lead on this.